# Is there a better way to do sandbox with Docker than what I'm doing below?

Tags: docker, containers, sandbox

I’m a new Docker user. I need to do the following:

1. Compile and run a random user’s C++ program on my machine (along
   with my own additions to their code)
2. Capture the output and process it locally.

I’m running docker on an Amazon AWS Linux micro instance. I did the following:

Customized and built an Ubuntu image called sandbox which has all the packages I need (g++, valgrind, make, etc.)

In a different directory which contains my pre-req files, I copy over the user’s files. Then I build a new docker image from this directory which builds using the sandbox base image. My Docker file says:

```
FROM sandbox
COPY . /sandbox
RUN make
```

Then I run a Docker build command from my local environment as follows:

```
307 {aws-028}testcpp: docker build --tag=test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  35.33kB
Step 1/5 : FROM        sandbox
 ---> 42fdf2be6912
Step 2/5 : MAINTAINER  AVFILT
 ---> Running in d5531528333c
Removing intermediate container d5531528333c
 ---> 561070a04095
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /sandbox
 ---> Running in 7d1afb32f3ef
Removing intermediate container 7d1afb32f3ef
 ---> e416508e5180
Step 4/5 : COPY . /sandbox
 ---> 8392a378a6a2
Step 5/5 : RUN make
 ---> Running in bf041f3a5353
g++ -Wall -O0 -std=c++0x *.cpp 
valgrind ./a.out  # >a.log 2>&1
==22== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22== Command: ./a.out
==22== 
Success. All tests passed. Congratulations.
==22== 
==22== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==22==   total heap usage: 3,881 allocs, 3,880 frees, 524,711 bytes allocated
==22== 
==22== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==22==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==22== 
==22== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Removing intermediate container bf041f3a5353
 ---> 9cf23028b470
Successfully built 9cf23028b470
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

I capture the above output into a local file and then process it using a script.

My question: Is this the best way to accomplish what I want (essentially the output of make and valgrind)?

If I do this iteratively a number of times, can I assume that each run will not leave behind dangling data to be cleaned up (and eventually run out of disk space)?

Thank you very much,

&

Answer (score 0):

> If I do this iteratively a number of times, can I assume that each run will not leave behind dangling data to be cleaned up (and eventually run out of disk space)?

You are guaranteed that each run *will* leave behind dangling data to be cleaned up: each `docker build` run creates a new image, and those stick around until explicitly removed.  That includes the complete valgrind log file and whatever else gets built and generated by the `Makefile`.

Instead you might consider whether you can directly use your `sandbox` image, and use the `docker run -v` option to inject the code you're trying to build (and the `docker run --rm` option to automatically clean up the container when it exits).

Comment: Thank you very much David. I now do:

docker run -v /usr/local/path/to/my/host/directory:/sandbox sandbox make

which works perfectly. In fact I now simply capture the output of make into a file which I can read from the host system after the container exits.

&